# Transaction rollback fail

Tags: c#, mysql

I facing problem when i trying to rollback my transaction if there is an error appear.

What i did is :

1) Insert into table A

2) Get the last inserted ID from table A

3) Insert into Table B

Below is my code:

```
 public Int32 insertECN(RegisterECN modelRegister)
    {

        IDataAccess access = this.CreateAccess(true);
        // true in createAccess will create an transaction
        try
        {
            DAparam[] param = new DAparam[]
           {
                new DAparam("@loginDate", modelRegister.loginDate),
                new DAparam("@ectype", modelRegister.ecType),
                new DAparam("@ecRecDate", modelRegister.ecReceiveDate),
                new DAparam("@ecRef", modelRegister.ecReference),
                new DAparam("@changeDesc", modelRegister.changeDescription),
                new DAparam("@reasonOfChan", modelRegister.reasonOfChange),
                new DAparam("@reworkIns", modelRegister.reworkInstructionsSummary),
                new DAparam("@remark", modelRegister.remarks),
                new DAparam("@custName", modelRegister.customerName),
                new DAparam("@proName", modelRegister.projectName),
                new DAparam("@ecOwnerName", modelRegister.ownerName),
                new DAparam("@materialImpact", modelRegister.materialImpact)

            };
            access.ExecSQL(SQL.registerNewECNToDB, param);

            //registerNewECNToDB =   **INSERT INTO eccs_registerecn_tbl(LOGINDATE,ECTYPE,ECRECEIVEDATE,ECREFERENCE,CHANGEDESCRIPTION,
              REASONOFCHANGE,REWORKINSTRUCTIONSUMMARY,REMARKS,CUSTOMERNAME,PROJECTNAME,ECOWNERNAME,MATERIALIMPACT) VALUES(@loginDate, @ectype,
              @ecRecDate, @ecRef, @changeDesc, @reasonOfChan, @reworkIns, @remark, @custName, @proName, @ecOwnerName, @materialImpact)**



            DataTable result2 = new DataTable();
            result2 = access.GetDataSet(SQL.selectLastID).Tables[0].Copy();

            //selectLastID = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'ID'


            int lastID = 0;
            lastID = Convert.ToInt32(result2.Rows[0][0]);


            DAparam[] param1 = new DAparam[]
                        {
                             new DAparam("@file", content),
                             new DAparam("@moduleRef", "ECN"),
                             new DAparam("@refID", lastID),
                             new DAparam("@fileName", file.FileName),
                             new DAparam("@fileType", file.ContentType)

                        };

            access.ExecSQL(SQL.insertAttachment, param1);

            // insertAttachment = INSERT INTO eccs_attachments_tbl(FILE,MODULEREF,REFID,FILENAME,FILETYPE) VALUES(@file, @moduleRef,@refID,@fileName,@fileType)

            return lastID;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            access.Rollback();

            throw new Exception("Unable to create ECN.. Please contact IT..", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (access != null)
            {
                access.Dispose();
            }
        }


    }
```

If there is any error appear when I insert data into Table B, my Table A transaction not able to rollback.

But if I try to delete the SELECT LAST ID query, it able to rollback successfully. May I know why and how can I solve this problem ?
is it cannot consists of SELECT and INSERT query in one transaction ?

Comment: Are you sure it is because of the `Select` query? That seems odd. What database server are you using

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks for your reply.. I not sure whether is because of the select query.. Because when i delete the statement, then it will rollback correctly. I am using MySQL database server.